# Mapping printers with VBS script

Tags: vbscript

I've been trying to map several different printers by security group using the following VBS script without much luck anyone have any recommendations?

```
Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
 Set objNetwork = CreateObject("Wscript.Network")
    
 strUserPath = "LDAP://" & objSysInfo.UserName
 Set objUser = GetObject(strUserPath)
    
 For Each strGroup in objUser.MemberOf
     strGroupPath = "LDAP://" & strGroup
     Set objGroup = GetObject(strGroupPath)
     strGroupName = objGroup.CN
    
     Select Case strGroupName
         Case "Finance Users"
             WshNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\testserver\testprinter1"
    
         Case "Human Resource Users" 
             WshNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\testserver\testprinter1"
    
         Case "Manufacturing Users"
             WshNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\testserver\testprinter1"
    
         Case "Shipping and Receiving Users"
             WshNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\testserver\testprinter1"
     End Select
 Next
```

Comment: First : You should get rid from the smart quotes when you copy from the net !
With this batch you can do it easily [Replacing_SmartQuotes.bat](https://pastebin.com/9Qcb615g)
Second : Get rid from `On Error Resume Next`

Comment: And what's your problem exactly? Any errors? If so, on which line of the script do they happen?